# Strange gzip - almost extracted, but not totally correct

Tags: python, gzip

Some program sends some info that starts with `\x1f\xe2\x80\xb9\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00M...` to the server and receives the text response. I need to guess what info is it.

In fact, I need the method to convert the real string to that identical gzipped original string to receive responses without that program.

After the investigation I've found that first I should decode data from utf8 to cp1251 (after that the first symbols `\x1f\xe2\x80\xb9\x08` will be `\x1f\8b\x08` that is typical gzip magic string). It will be corrupted gzip, but if I cut it's header (first 10 symbols) I can extract the final readable message.

But this message is little corrupted (starts correctly, but later some symbols are shuffled).

What should be done to properly read the data?

I guess that during decode_binary_from_utf8_to_cp1251 I loose some info, because if I don't use on_errors='replace' the data can't be converted correctly (I've tried others encoding that also do `\x1f\xe2\x80\xb9\x08` to `\x1f\8b\x08` magic but without success, no of encoding were able to convert 100% without errors). And also when I cut the header (first 10 symbols of the gzipped string) some data also can be missed.

My code:

```
import zlib
import base64


def decode_binary_from_utf8_to_cp1251(data):
    enc_from = "utf8"
    enc_to = "cp1251"
    on_errors = "replace"
    # on_errors = ""
    return data.decode(enc_from, on_errors).encode(enc_to, on_errors)


def remove_archive_signature_from_start(data):
    return data[10:]


def decompress_gzip(body):
    args = (-zlib.MAX_WBITS | 16,)  # working
    return zlib.decompress(body, *args)


def convert_binary_to_normal_text(b, encoding="cp1251"):
    b = b.decode(encoding, "replace")
    return b


base64_encoded = "L2dldC8f4oC5CAAAAAAABABN4oCZX+KAmdCrIAzQltCH0KLQ ... gMAAA=="

data = base64.b64decode(base64_encoded)[5:]
# data = b'\x1f\xe2\x80\xb9\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00...\x03\x00\x00'

new_data = decode_binary_from_utf8_to_cp1251(data)
new_data = remove_archive_signature_from_start(new_data)

decompressed = decompress_gzip(new_data)
normal_text = convert_binary_to_normal_text(decompressed)

print(f"{normal_text=}")
```

returns text like

```
...
;btennis,1oatchoomkcom®1i,hoomkcomwilliamhillmkcomwom;bein.zegoalbet.cal;bmosityom;beokt;favet.colpasbein.zeni;bmosbet.learathssityligbetavtchoomkpar)rrathssitnoarathoinfo
...
```

, starts correctly, but later some symbols are shuffled (because I know exactly that it should include string `;wwin.com;zebet.com;baltbet.ru;winlinebet.com;golpas.com;zenitbet.com;leonbets.ru;ligastavok.com;parimatch.com;fonbet.info®`)

Any ideas what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Some program" has a bug that needs to be fixed. In general, UTF encoding is not lossless so the original data is not recoverable. That program needs to *not* do any such conversion, and instead send the original binary.

I was able to recover the original gzip file from the example by using the table on the [Windows-1251 Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251), with an addition. You will note that that table has nothing for the character `0x98`. I assume that the unicode symbol `U+0098` translates to the byte `0x98`. Applying that translation and dropping the first five bytes of the result gives a valid gzip stream with a correct CRC and length check.

There is no guarantee that this will work in general, since the provided example does not have all possible byte values.

Comment: No bug, because it returns the correct answer to their prime gzipped string. I can make a check at any time - I can take the final readable string, apply reversed functions in reversed order and get the prime gzipped string. And send that string to the server. But the server returns the correct answer to their gzipped string and returns error on my gzipped string. So I'm losing something and I'm looking for what it is.

Comment: And I have no control over that program. I need to explore the way it encodes "questions" and encode my new "questions" to receive the actual answer without the program.

Comment: What is "it", who is "their", and how exactly do you "make a check at any time"? How are you getting this data? Show your code. "Some program" may be sending the binary, but perhaps _you_ are doing the lossy conversion.

Comment: I've edited my code. The program sends the exact `base64_encoded` string (after decoding first 5 bytes are `/get/`. I can make a check at any time because I can post such data to the same URL the program does and receive the same answer. Program 100% of times returns a correct answer on their own  `base64_encoded` strings.

Comment: Then, yes, "some program" definitely has a bug. regardless of whether or not they can losslessly recover the original binary compressed data. Given that the data is base64 encoded, there is no reason whatsoever to corrupt and expand the compressed data, by about 50%!, with a UTF encoding.

Comment: They definitely can losslessly recover the original binary compressed data because they 100% of time return the correct answer to their compressed data. Maybe this is some sort of protecting the data? Some check against people like me who try to "recover" the algorithm?

Comment: If that was their objective, they could have simply encrypted the data, requiring no expansion. You should just ask them how to decode it.

Comment: I have no option to ask them. Maybe they use their format of data? For example they send some part that compressed gzipped cp1251 (so I should use decode_binary_from_utf8_to_cp1251 only to the first part of the data, for example before the first symbol that is not convertible exactly to 1251) and some other kind of data (and they use real utf8 for this)? Or maybe it is possible that iteration through all charsets in decode_binary_from_utf8_to_cp1251 (not only utf8 to cp1251) will give me the variant that will be decompressed correctly? Any more ideas? I'll try all the possible variants.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **@Mark Adler** , that new version of `decode_binary_from_utf8_to_cp1251` solved the issue:

```
def decode_binary_from_utf8_to_cp1251(data, enc_from="utf8", enc_to="cp1251"):
    data = data_correction_before(data)
    data = data.decode(enc_from)
    data = data.encode(enc_to)
    data = data_correction_after(data)
    return data


def data_correction_before(data):
    return data.replace(b"\xc2\x98", b"__WRONG__")


def data_correction_after(data):
    return data.replace(b"__WRONG__", b"\x98")
```

Comment: Of course, if `__WRONG__` appears in the original data, this won't work. The only reliable solution would be to implement your own conversion from UTF-8 to Windows-1251.